# default value are not properly reflected for the same keys from 2 different but closely related ruby code

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.3

Please follow the below code :

***Part-I***

```
> h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
> h.default = "Go fish"
=> "Go fish"
> h["a"]
=> 100
> h["z"]
=> "Go fish"
> h.default = proc do |hash, key|
*   hash[key] = key + key
> end
=> #<Proc:0x208bee8@(irb):5>
> h[2]
=> #<Proc:0x208bee8@(irb):5>
> h["cat"]
=> #<Proc:0x208bee8@(irb):5>
```

***Part-II***

```
> h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
> h.default_proc = proc do |hash, key|
*   hash[key] = key + key
> end
=> #<Proc:0x1e21df8@(irb):2>
> h[2]
=> 4
> h["cat"]
=> "catcat"
```

Now I am surprised to see, why `h[2] and h["cat"]` giving different output for the two codes in `part-I and part-II`.

Could you anyone please explain?

Comment: There's no surprise for me. `default` set the static default object(as you can see, the objectId is the same), while `default_proc` is something to be eval-ed.

Comment: @halfelf i didn't get your point! a bit explanation in more details would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Hash#default=` sets the value to be **returned** in case there is no such key. You set that to a proc in Part-I, and that is what you see being returned.
- `Hash#default_proc=` sets the proc to be **called on itself and the key** in case there is no such key. If you do `hash[2] = 2 + 2`, then `hash[2]` will return `4`. If you do `hash["cat"] = "cat" + "cat"`, then `hash["cat"]` will return `"catcat"`.

Comment: Perfect explanation! `+1` to you!

Comment: Could you please say what to be used in what situation? means any real time programming example where i have to set the `part-I` settings for defaulting and one areas where i have to chose `part-II` settings?

Comment: @VBSlover Maps of procs are an easy way to associated functionality with keys, for example, a simple state machine or external DSL.

Comment: When you want the default to be a constant, for example the same `:foo` to whatever key, then you can use `default=`. If you want it to vary depending on the key, then you need to use `default_proc=`.

Comment: @sawa if you don't mind can you show me a tiny code against your statement,which might be better to understand! please :)

Answer (score 2):

**Why?** (Philosophical)

What if you wanted a hash of `Proc`s? You can't just set the default *value* to be a `Proc` *to run*, because there wouldn't be a (trivial) mechanism to distinguish it from a `Proc` to *return*.

Maps of `Proc`s might be used to implement a simple state machine or external DSL.

**Why?** (Technical)

Because that's the way `[]` is written:

```c
VALUE
rb_hash_aref(VALUE hash, VALUE key)
{
    st_data_t val;

    if (!RHASH(hash)->ntbl || !st_lookup(RHASH(hash)->ntbl, key, &val)) {
        if (!FL_TEST(hash, HASH_PROC_DEFAULT) &&
            rb_method_basic_definition_p(CLASS_OF(hash), id_default)) {
            return RHASH_IFNONE(hash);
        }
        else {
            return rb_funcall(hash, id_default, 1, key);
        }
    }
    return (VALUE)val;
}
```

As the docs to `default` say:

> It is not possible to set the default to a Proc that will be executed on each key lookup.

Comment: Perfect explanation! `+1` to you! and also thank you very much to give such 2 `why?s`